# How to clone old small SSD into new larger replacement SSD in a laptop

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, ssd, dualboot, disk-cloning

I have a Thinkpad with a 500GB SSD, and it's split into a dual-boot of a 100GB Windows 10 partition and a 400GB Ubuntu partition. (Note: I'm comfortable nuking the 100GB Windows partition because nothing important is on it.)

I also have a 1TB Windows 10 desktop.

I want to merge all of the data I care about (i.e. the Windows 10 desktop and the Ubuntu partition of the Thinkpad) into 1 new SSD that I'll install in the Thinkpad.

To clarify: I want to buy a 2TB SSD to replace the SSD in the Thinkpad, and I want it to be a dual-boot where 500GB is for Ubuntu and 1.5 TB is for Windows.

##### How can I clone my desktop's 1TB Windows partition onto the 1.5TB partition of a new SSD and clone my Thinkpad's current/old 400GB partition into the 500GB of the new SSD?

Is there hardware I can buy, or are there services that can do this (locally or at my home) without me shipping my drives somewhere?

Comment: You won’t be able to transfer your Windows installation from your desktop and boot it on your laptop.

Comment: It seems overly complicated if you mean combine all by cloning. I do not think it will work. Put the largest drive you can in your ThinkPad (I have 1 TB in mine), set it up and copy what you want to it.

Comment: @Ramhound Why not?

Comment: Beyond the fact your laptop has an OEM license and your desktop doesn’t, I am going to guess, the hardware is vastly different

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not copy the Ubuntu partition. But it clones the desktop Windows installation to the new SSD and then you can install Ubuntu dual boot.

First check if the desktop Windows installation is UEFI. If it is not UEFI and your Thinkpad supports UEFI then it's not a good idea to use this installation at all. The reason is performance and security (secure boot). See this [link](https://www.easyuefi.com/resource/check-windows-is-booted-in-uefi-mode.html). It is possible to use the installation even if it's not UEFI. But then you will have to enable compatibility mode in the Thinkpad's BIOS/UEFI settings.

Put the new 2TB SSD into a USB case like [this one](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00OJ3UJ2S). Then start your Windows 10 desktop PC from a live Ubuntu USB pen drive.

Clone the desktop 1TB HDD to the 2TB SSD like this (Replace sdXXX with the desktop disk and sdYYY with the 2TB SSD. Use `lsblk` to list disks. Be careful and use at your own risk.):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdXXX of=/dev/sdYYY bs=4M status=progress conv=fsync
```

Now put the 2TB SSD into the Thinkpad and see if it boots. Shut down the Thinkpad and boot from the live USB pen drive. Resize the Windows 10 partition to 1,5TB using `gparted` or `ntfsresize`.

Check again if it still boots.

Then you can install Ubuntu dual boot from the live USB pen drive.